# Excel VBA End Select without Select Case

Tags: excel, vba

I am making a program to take data from a spreadsheet regarding products, gather their info, and calculate if more needs to be ordered.  I have been trying to get a Select Case statement working and no matter how I code it, I get the same error.  i've done it in a while loop, in a for loop, and by itself.  Error persists "End Select without Select Case" which as you can see isn't right.

```
  Sub Ordering()
Dim VendorName, Product As String
Dim Counter, ProductOffset, OnHand, OnHandOffset, OnOrder, OnOrderOffset, Commited, CommitedOffset As Integer

ProductOffset = 14 'columns out from A
OnHandOffset = 19
OnOrderOffset = 20
CommitedOffset = 21
Counter = 0

'start active cell in top left
Range("A1").Select

    'grab product code
    Product = ActiveCell.Offset(0, ProductOffset).Value
    OnHand = ActiveCell.Offset(0, OnHandOffset).Value
    OnOrder = ActiveCell.Offset(0, OnOrderOffset).Value
    Commited = ActiveCell.Offset(0, CommitedOffset).Value

    Select Case Product
        Case "100HB"
            If (OnHand + OnOrder - Commited) <= 1000 Then
                MsgBox ("Found 100HB")

    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Missing the closing `End If` after `MsgBox ("Found 100HB")`, which shouldn't have any parentheses btw.

Comment: Or you can also add underscore after `Then` which may remove the needs of `End IF` i.e. `<= 1000 Then _`

Comment: @Bilal while legal, that is a very terrible thing to inflict upon future maintainers (i.e. future you).

Answer (score 4):

The compiler works its way down the procedure from the top. When it encounters a "block start", it doesn't skip to the bottom to try and find the corresponding "block end". Instead it stacks up "block start" tokens and when it encounters a "block end" token, it pops that stack and compares to what it's expecting: if it's expecting `End If` but instead finds `End Select`, a compile (syntax) error is thrown:

- Enter the `Select Case` block. Expected end-block: `End Select`
- Enter the `If` block in the first case. Expected end-block: `End If`
- Encounter `End Select`, expected `End If` => throw "end select without select case" syntax error

It's good to know that the `If` statement in VBA has two legal syntaxes:

1. Block syntax

   That's `If {bool-expression} Then`, immediately followed by a NEWLINE. To be legal, there needs to be an `End If` token further down, to close that block. If you always consistently hit ENTER after typing `Then`, and immediately type `End If` and insert & indent one line of code in-between, you'll never again hit this syntax/compile error in your lifetime.
2. Inline syntax

   That's `If {bool-expression} Then {expression}`, which is what [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66992552/excel-vba-end-select-without-select-case#comment118418181_66992552) is suggesting to do... by introducing a *line continuation* token `{SPACE}_{NEWLINE}` to have the `{expression}` part on a separate line... which makes it *read/look* like the block syntax if you're not careful. It also makes it harder than necessary to later add more conditional expressions, because then you must add the `End If` token.